# The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linx/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm attempting to install docker to my vm instances of Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 LTS. After following the instructions from the official Docker documentation, I hit an obstacle that I'm stumped on.

While running this command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

The pull down gets hung up when it's not able to retrieve the release file. If I go to the link from the browser it takes me to the repo pool no problem

```
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:4 https://download.docker.com/linx/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linx/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.101.21 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linx/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N:: command not found
dan@chapter:~$ N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Some of the solutions I tried were reconfiguring my locales. Removing any entries in the `sources.list`. I also tried using the `test` and `edge` releases instead, but I'm still seeing the same error.

Like I said, I'm pretty stumped and would be appreciative if anyone can point out what maybe right under my nose. :)

Comment: When you ran `apt-add-repository`, you missed a "u" in `linux` in the URL; you can edit files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to fix this.  (But note that Stack Overflow is much more about actual programming questions than just "how do I install Docker"; the [help/on-topic] has more details.)

Comment: There's nothing in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. When I ran the command `add-apt-repository` the string is correct. It makes me curious why only the release file contains the typo.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I went back to the `sources.list` file and sure enough, I found the link with the typo. Here I thought the link would stay commented after removing it from the terminal.